# Setting up multiple Windows VM's on an Ubuntu server

Tags: server

Currently I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server with SSH. I am trying to setup multiple Windows virtual machines on it that can be access through the browser (like remote desktop) but I'm not sure what approach would be the best. I have a very powerful server, so resources won't be an issue. I also want to restrict the Windows machines similar to how public machines are normally restricted (library computers, ect). Could anyone help me with my first few steps?